# compiling boost for wince

Tags: visual-studio-2008, boost, windows-ce

when creating a visual studio 2008 (version 9.0) project for my wince target visual studio knows about my platorm which is "FSS5PV210_CE6 (ARMV4I)". this platform is predefined by the vendor and installed via an sdk and causes visual studio magically to know its include directory. I cant't see it in the command line that is shown by vs.
so the question is: how does vs inject the include dir into the compiler?

for boost i added the following to user-config.jam:

```
using msvc : 9.0~armstone : "cl.exe" :
<compileflags>-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
<compileflags>-D_WIN32_WCE=0x600
<compileflags>-DUNDER_CE
<compileflags>-DBSP_FSS5PV210
<compileflags>-DWINCE
<compileflags>-DARM
<compileflags>-D_ARM_
<compileflags>-DARMV4I
<compileflags>-D_LITTLE_ENDIAN
<compileflags>-DUNICODE
<compileflags>-D_UNICODE
<compileflags>-DPOCKETPC2003_UI_MODEL
<compileflags>-DBOOST_NO_STD_LOCALE
<compileflags>-D_MSC_VER=1500
<linkflags>/subsystem:windowsce,6.00
<linkflags>/machine:arm
<linkflags>/NODEFAULTLIB:oldnames.lib
<linkflags>/STACK:262144,4096
<linkflags>coredll.lib
<linkflags>corelibc.lib
<linkflags>ole32.lib
<linkflags>oleaut32.lib
<linkflags>uuid.lib
<linkflags>commctrl.lib
<architecture>arm
<instruction-set>armv4
<interface>wince
<assembler>"armasm.exe"
;
```

i then call bjam with
bjam.exe toolset=msvc-9.0~armstone variant=debug link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --prefix= --layout=tagged install

I again wonder how bjam can know about my platform and its include dir which is
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\wce600\FSS5PV210_CE6\Include\Armv4i"

-Jochen

Answer (score 0):

This works with the checksdk.exe commando:

```
checksdk -list

checksdk.exe -sdk "your sdk name" -script setenviroment.bat
```

In `setenvironment.bat` it sets a environment variable called `INCLUDE`. It also sets `PATH` and `LIB`. It sets `PATH` to make sure that the right cross compiler `cl.exe` is used (for example the x86_arm one in case you're compiling for arm), it sets `LIB` to help you link and `INCLUDE` is of course for compiling.

Comment: Where is located checksdk?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call from bjam a batch file that set the envirioment variables. This is done with the  option in you configuration file. For example:

```
using msvc : 9.0~armstone : "cl.exe" :
    <compileflags>-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    <compileflags>-D_WIN32_WCE=0x600
    <compileflags>-DUNDER_CE
    <compileflags>-DBSP_FSS5PV210
    <compileflags>-DWINCE
    <compileflags>-DARM
    <compileflags>-D_ARM_
    <compileflags>-DARMV4I
    <compileflags>-D_LITTLE_ENDIAN
    <compileflags>-DUNICODE
    <compileflags>-D_UNICODE
    <compileflags>-DPOCKETPC2003_UI_MODEL
    <compileflags>-DBOOST_NO_STD_LOCALE
    <compileflags>-D_MSC_VER=1500
    <linkflags>/subsystem:windowsce,6.00
    <linkflags>/machine:arm
    <linkflags>/NODEFAULTLIB:oldnames.lib
    <linkflags>/STACK:262144,4096
    <linkflags>coredll.lib
    <linkflags>corelibc.lib
    <linkflags>ole32.lib
    <linkflags>oleaut32.lib
    <linkflags>uuid.lib
    <linkflags>commctrl.lib
    <architecture>arm
    <instruction-set>armv4
    <interface>wince
    <assembler>"armasm.exe"
    <setup>armstoneconf.bat
;
```

int the batch file that I called armstoneconf.bat you have to set the PATH, INCLUDE, LIB and LIBPATH of the headers of your target.

In the user-config.jam you have to use the ARM compiler and not the x86 one. I think is located in %VCInstallDir%ce/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe and not the "cl.exe" that is for desktop target.

You can create a simple vc solution and see what visual studio use.

Look also at: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906901/build-boost-c-wince